# Creating a binary variable with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I have a dataset for the lifetime(after a surgery) of a patient and the age of the patient and have to make a binary variable for the following:

The medical department of the hospital assumes that the estimated life of a patient is 85 years, and states that a patient survived a certain disease if the following rule applies. If the patient lived more than 25% of the remaining life time from current age till the estimated life time, then the patient is considered as “surviver” from the disease. When this is not the case, it is assumed that the patient died from the diagnosed disease, hence “non-surviver”. As the patient data set does not yet have this binary target feature, you need to create such binary variable for conducting the further classification analysis.

I made the following expression but do not know if it is right.

data["Survived"] = (((85-data['Age'])*0.25) <= (data['LifeTime']/365)) * 1

[Dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyGSq.png)

Comment: Can you provide an example item from the data set? It is unclear to me what `LifeTime` is (guessing it is a number of days given then division by 365.

Comment: The LifeTime is the amount of days a patient lives after the surgery. Age is in years

Comment: It would be great if you could show what the data looks like.

Comment: @Danny formula looks good to me when I try it with some data that I made up. Someone who is 70 has to survive for 1368.75 (15*365 *0.25) days to be classed as a survivor

Comment: I added an example

Comment: What value do you have in Age and LifeTime. Is LifeTime calculated from Age or is that a value given by default?

Comment: Also, if some is currently 40 yrs old and the patient lives for more than 25% chance of the life, then the patient is 50 yrs old. My question is: Will the estimated LifeTime of the patient become 50 yrs or are we to figure out based on additional inputs?